# Unable to get default constructor for class UnitTests.TestDemoClass

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, microsoft-fakes

Getting below error while running TestDemoClass method. I have written testcases in this class using Microsoft Fakes .

```
Error:

Message: Unable to get default constructor for class UnitTests.TestDemoClass
```

I have tried below code to create constructor in TestDemoClass.

```
   public TestDemoClass(string storageConnectionString)
        {
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Fakes.ShimCloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Fakes.ShimCloudStorageAccount();         
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Fakes.ShimCloudStorageAccount.AllInstances.CreateCloudBlobClient = (x) =>
            {
                return sampleBlobClient;
            };
            blobClient = sampleBlobClient;
        }
```

DemoClass constructor looks like below

```
 public DemoClass(string storageConnectionString)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        }
```

How to resolve above issue.